# Underline text - line thickness in crossing ranges with different font sizes

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

I am working with the attributes of textStorage of `UITextView`. I have the string and an array of the objects of my class `TextFormattingElement`. An instance of this class consists of `NSRange` (on which this element has to be applied in text) and some formatting parameters:

```
@interface TextFormattingElement : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSRange range;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fontName;   //e.g. @"TimesNewRomanPSMT"
@property (nonatomic) int fontSize;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *fontColor;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isBold;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isItalic;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isUnderlined;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isStriked;

@end
```

Now i loop through this array and successively apply this elements to the textStorage of textView. I use this method:

```
-(void)setFontWithName:(NSString*)name AndSize:(float)fontSize AndTextColor:(UIColor*)textColor AndIsBold:(BOOL)isBold AndIsItalic:(BOOL)isItalic AndIsUnderlined:(BOOL)isUnderLined andIsStriked:(BOOL)isStriked ToRange:(NSRange)rangeToSet{
   __block UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:fontSize];
   __block UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [font fontDescriptor];

   [textView.textStorage enumerateAttributesInRange:rangeToSet options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
      NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [attrs objectForKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

      NSMutableDictionary *attributesToSetDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     [attributesToSetDict setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];  //i need to clear all attributes at this range exсept NSParagraphStyleAttributeName

      if(isBold){
          uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold;
          fontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];
      }

      if(isItalic){
          uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic;
          fontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];
      }

      font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:fontSize];
      [attributesToSetDict setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
      [attributesToSetDict setObject:textColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

      if(isUnderLined){
          [attributesToSetDict setObject:@1 forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
      }

      if(isStriked){
          //TODO: isStriked
      }

      [textView.textStorage setAttributes:attributesToSetDict range:range];
    }];
  }
```

I have one problem: if i have two `TextFormattingElement` instances with crossing ranges (e.g. `NSMakeRange(9,28)` and `NSMakeRange(26,7)`) the thickness of underline has always the value dependent of the last element's font size. The illustration of this you can see at this screenshot:

[image]

The parameters of my 2 formatting elements are:

**1st: location = 9, length = 28, fontName = TimesNewRomanPSMT, fontSize = 15, fontColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, isBold = 0, isItalic = 0, isUnderlined = 1, isStriked = 0**

**2nd: location = 26, length = 7, fontName = TimesNewRomanPSMT, fontSize = 25, fontColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1, isBold = 1, isItalic = 0, isUnderlined = 1, isStriked = 0**

But I want to get an effect like in Google Docs:

[image]

How can I do this using TextKit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On iOS 7 you can do what you want with a subclass of `NSLayoutManager` that override `-drawUnderlineForGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:`
A little sample that create text system objects, and draw the wanted underline.

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup text handling with our subclass of NSLayoutManager
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@"Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do;"];

    MyLayoutManager *textLayout = [[MyLayoutManager alloc] init];

    [textStorage addLayoutManager:textLayout];

    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];

    [textLayout addTextContainer:textContainer];
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-20)
                                               textContainer:textContainer];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

    // setup test attributes
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:15];

    NSMutableDictionary *attributesToSetDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [attributesToSetDict setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributesToSetDict setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [attributesToSetDict setObject:@1 forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];

    [textView.textStorage setAttributes:attributesToSetDict range:NSMakeRange(9, 28)];

    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [font fontDescriptor];
    attributesToSetDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [attributesToSetDict setObject:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:25] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributesToSetDict setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [attributesToSetDict setObject:@1 forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];

    [textView.textStorage setAttributes:attributesToSetDict range:NSMakeRange(26, 7)];
}
@end

@implementation MyLayoutManager
- (void)drawUnderlineForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange underlineType:(NSUnderlineStyle)underlineVal baselineOffset:(CGFloat)baselineOffset lineFragmentRect:(CGRect)lineRect lineFragmentGlyphRange:(NSRange)lineGlyphRange containerOrigin:(CGPoint)containerOrigin
{
    /* For the sample we consider that underlineVal is equals to NSUnderlineStyleSingle */

    /*
     * We need to create a CTFontRef as UIFont doesn't provided 'Underline Position' and 'Underline Thickness'
     */

    // get current UIFont for the glyphRange
    NSRange characterRange = [self characterRangeForGlyphRange:glyphRange actualGlyphRange:NULL];
    UIFont *font = [[self.textStorage attributesAtIndex:characterRange.location effectiveRange:NULL] objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    CTFontRef ctfont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)[font fontName], [font pointSize], NULL);

    CGPoint startLocation = [self locationForGlyphAtIndex:glyphRange.location];
    CGPoint endLocation = [self locationForGlyphAtIndex:NSMaxRange(glyphRange)];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // -underlineGlyphRange:underlineType:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin: already set color and line width
    // for the current context

    // reset line width with current font underline thickness
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, CTFontGetUnderlineThickness(ctfont));

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, startLocation.x + containerOrigin.x, startLocation.y + containerOrigin.y - CTFontGetUnderlinePosition(ctfont));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, endLocation.x + containerOrigin.x, endLocation.y + containerOrigin.y - CTFontGetUnderlinePosition(ctfont));

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CFRelease(ctfont);
}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you! I also started working in this direction but had a problem with finding a formula for underline thickness and underline indent from the characters. Now with your answer i know how to do it with Core Text. Big thank to you thousands times!!!